# Trouble parsing JSON to string in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    data: [
    {
        objectType: "ServiceForbiddenException",
        item: {
            service: "users",
            action: "index",
            code: 403,
            message: "Access to the service [users] is forbidden."
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

I tried parsing it using the following snippet:

```
       String bodyData = iRes.body().string();
       try{
            JSONObject body = new JSONObject(bodyData);
            JSONArray data = body.getJSONArray("data");
            JSONObject type =  data.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray item = data.getJSONArray(1);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the problem is that is that `JSONArray data = body.getJSONArray("data");`is actually the whole data, and not an array.

How do I parse it correctly? are there better libs / ways to parse a json in Java (Android)

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. You could look in to [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for a JSON parser.

Comment: Looks valid to me.  He has a parsing error though.

Comment: @karaokyo thanks for assisting.
I tested it in [Link](http://jsonlint.com/) and came out valid

Comment: @GabeSechan, where is the error? how should I parse it? thank you

Comment: This json is valid when I check `{
    "data": {
        "objectType": "ServiceForbiddenException",
        "item": {
            "service": "users",
            "action": "index",
            "code": 403,
            "message": "Access to the service [users] is forbidden."
        }
    }
}` unless you need the data object to be an array

Comment: To make it proper JSON you would need to surround keys with `"`.

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks, what needs to be changed if I want it to be an array?

Comment: Surround the object with brackets -  `{
    "data": [
        {
            "objectType": "ServiceForbiddenException",
            "item": {
                "service": "users",
                "action": "index",
                "code": 403,
                "message": "Access to the service [users] is forbidden."
            }
        }
    ]
}` - like you had it. Just didn't know if you needed it to be an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are created using `{}`, arrays are created using `[]`. So

```
data:[
 { }
]
```

is array labelled as `data` which contains only one object (unlabelled, but indexed as `0`), so calling

```
data.getJSONArray(1);
```

doesn't make sense here, because it would try to find

```
data:[
 { }
 [ ] <-this, but you don't have it in your JSON
]
```

What you seem to want is getting `item` *object* which is part of object you already got from array and stored in `type`.

So instead of

```
JSONArray item = data.getJSONArray(1);
```

use

```
JSONObject item = type.getJSONObject("item");
^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^ - things you need to change
```

Comment: Actually there is not many things to read. I think http://json.org/ covers all important details about JSON structure.

Answer (score 1):

Data is an array of objects (with only 1 object in the example).  So your type should be `type =  data.getJSONObject(0).getString("objectType")`;  and `item = type =  data.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("item")`;  Notice item is a JSONObject, not a JSONArray.

If you need to process all the items in data, loop over them and change the index you're getting from 0.

Actually looking at your code-  you seem to be a little confused on Objects and Arrays in general.  You might want to read up on them, with respect to JSON.

Comment: You are quite right here :) now, I am confused. Can you point out what I am missing? or recommend any good article?

Thank you :)